# Set property value

Tags: javascript

I need to change the value of a javascript property but nothing seem to work. This is what I tried:

```
var test = allProducts[i]; // allProducts[i] comes from the database
console.log("TestProp BEFORE = " + test.get("TestProp"));
```

This prints out my `TestValue`.

Now I try to change the value and I tried all 3 syntax suggestions below (not at the same time of course):

```
test.TestProp = "kisses";
test["TestProp"] = "kisses2";
test['TestProp'] = "kisses3";
console.log("TestProp AFTER = " + test.get("TestProp"));
```

But this once again prints my `TestValue`.

What am I missing? Could it be that the object is somehow locked?

Comment: Let me guess - you're using `Backbone`, right?

Comment: what is the `.get()` method?

Comment: Ah, anyway. Try using `test.set('TestProp', 'kisses')` instead.

Comment: BTW, 3 syntax suggestions you mentioned are actually equivalent.

Comment: @raina77ow you should probably make the test.set() comment an answer ;)

Comment: test.set('','') works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, when you see something like `SomeObject.get('attrName')` in the code, it's a sure-sign `SomeObject` is actually not a plain JS object. Many popular frameworks (including Backbone) and libraries (jQuery) use the following approach: instead of enhancing native/host Objects, they put those into properly formed containers ('favor composition over inheritance' principle).

The bottom line is that while it might be possible to assign properties to these wrapper-objects (with bracket or dot notation), it's meaningless. Instead one has to use proper `setter` methods - most commonly, it's `set()`.

In your case, that resolves to...

```
test.set('TestProp', 'some_kisses_value');
```

... where the first param is the name of attribute/property, the second one is its value.

Comment: Thanks @raina. This works but now I'm getting a weird Parse.com error when I try to send this object from the server (the cloud) to my ios app. Would you know anything about this: Error: Uncaught Tried to save an object with a pointer to a new, unsaved object.

Comment: @Eddy Because you missed the explanation: `SomeObject` is _not_ a plain JS object, it's a wrapper. And it's library-dependent how to extract this plain object - in Backbone, for example, one can access `SomeObject.attributes` (property, not method).

Comment: Actually it's a weird behavior by Parse.com. I'm now using the set notation successfully, and adding properties to the backbone object that comes from the datastore, but I *still* need to save it before sending it to the client (the ios app.) There's no need to save it -- I haven't changed any of the actual properties and it's a complete waste of datastore call -- but if I don't I get the error from my comment above.